# seam 2.2 with microsoft access

Tags: database, eclipse, ms-access, seam, jboss-tools

is it possible to import a MS access database (.mdb) in a seam project using JBoss tools within Eclipse (Ganymede)?
Starting a new seam project, I cannot see any field which uses ms access as database type.
Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Java programs generally talk to databases through JDBC drivers.  To my knowledge there is no JDBC driver for Access MDB files.  You can use the JDBC-ODBC bridge to create a connection to the Access database with a little help from the Access ODBC driver.  How to set up this construction is explained [here](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2691&lngWId=2)

You have to create a database connection in the JBoss application server that uses that connection, how this is done can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html/gettingstartedwithjbosstools.html#d0e3107).

Comment: As far i've seen no free jdbc driver for Access indeed. I tried using the bridge JDBC-ODBC but it didn't helped, because of hibernate issues. 
So the solution was to export the db to another dbms like MySQL and let JBoss tools generate entities from it. It didn't required any effort, above all if, as in this case, the MDB database was quite ..relational-less.
Thanks anyway